# How click ajax link?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
AjaxOptions ajaxMainArea = new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "main_area" };
@Ajax.ActionLink("new game", "Game", ajaxMainArea)
```

I need click in javascript.

```
function newgame(cost) {
    //here I need call ajax method
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("new game", "Game",null, ajaxMainArea,new { @id="aNewGame" })
```

and in your script, bind the functionality to your element.

```
$(function () {
    $("#aNewGame").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get("YourController/ActionMethod", { yourData: "someValue" }, function (response) {
          //Do whatever with the reponse.
        });
    });
});
```

Assuming you have jQuery loaded in your page.

If I am doing some custom stuff with links like that, i will just use the normal `ActionLink` HTML helper and bind the functionality to that like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("new game", "Game",null,new {@id="aNewGame"})
```

and the Script is

```
$(function () {
    $("#aNewGame").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("YourController/ActionMethod", { yourData: "someValue" }, function (response) {
          $("#main_area").html(response);
          //If you want to do something else, you can do it here. :)
        });
    });
});
```